# Why is tensorflow.map not working properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Whenever I run Tf.map, even when using a function very similar to the one used on the Tf.Data tutorial, I get an error:
self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
data = "*data\\*training\\*\\*"
filelist = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data))

classes = ('item0','item1','item2', 'item3')
def generator(file):
    f = tf.io.read_file(file)
    f = tf.image.decode_jpeg(f)
    f = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(tf.image.resize(f, size = [28,28, 3]))
    l = file.split('\\')
    l = l[2]
    l_label = classes.index(l)
    r1 = tf.constant(l_label)
    r2 = f
    return r1, r2 

def runModel():
    dataset = filelist.map(todataset)

def todataset(file):
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
        file = file.eval(session=session)
        print("I got here" + file)
        session.close()
    push_to_array1, push_to_array2 = generator(file.eval(session=session))
    return(push_to_array2, push_to_array1)


runModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the issue is with the tensorflow.map function itself?  I think there are some possible errors in the `todataset()` function that you wish to map--can you help us at all by clarifying what you want this function to do to each of the file names in the Dataset?

It looks like you try printing the name of the first file in the dataset within the `with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:` context block.  I think this leads to two potential errors with your code.  The first is that it should not be necessary to manually close the session before exiting the context, because python will automatically attempt to close the session when you leave the context.  Relatedly, you try to use the same `session` variable again outside of the context (in your call to the generator), where it is no longer defined.  The second is that you overwrite the value of the `file` tensor in the line `file = file.eval(session=session)`; after that line the value of `file` is (presumably) a string from the glob matched by the `filelist` Dataset.  However you call `file.eval()` again inline when you pass it to your generator.  A python string, however, has no `.eval()` method.

The quick fixes to these problems would be to remove all of the existing lines in the `with` block, and move your generator line into the block.  Without knowing the expected output of the `todataset` mapping, or the rest of the your intentions in `runModel`, however, it's hard to say if that will do everything that you want it to.